# CancellationTokenSource - closes the wrong task

Tags: c#, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Please tell me what is the mistake?
After execution of `Look 1`, an exception `Look 2` is thrown, instead of the end of `Look 3`.
Here is my code

```
private CancellationTokenSource Start()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Log.Info("INFO:", "Thread Start() begin !!!");
        Task.Run(async () => {
            try
            {
                await Send("Test");
                var res = await Read(WAIT_ANSWER_TO);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Log.Info("INFO:", "Thread Start() canceled !!!");//Look 2
            }
        }, cts.Token);
        return cts;//for external closure
    }
public async Task<string> Read(int milisecond)
    {
        string line = "";
        var c = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Action<string> fun = (s) =>
        {
            line = s;
            c.Cancel();//Look 1
        };
        NewLine += fun;
        await Task.Delay(milisecond, c.Token);//Look 3
        NewLine -= fun;
        return line;
    }
private void Reader()
    {
        Log.Info("INFO:", "Thread Reader() begin !!!");
        Task.Run(async () => {
            try
            {
                var bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Socket.InputStream));
                while (true)
                {
                    var res = await bufReader.ReadLineAsync();
                    if (NewLine != null) NewLine(res);
                }
            }
            catch(Java.IO.IOException)
            {
                Log.Info("INFO:", "Thread Reader() canceled !!!");//because socked closed
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This code is *way* too complicated. Too many CTSs, and Tasks aren't threads to begin with.  In any case, `await Task.Delay(milisecond, c.Token);` throws an exception that's caught by `catch (OperationCanceledException)`. There's only one exception involved.

Comment: `NewLine` whatever it is, isn't needed. If you wanted to cancel when a newline arrives, just return from `Reader`. Reader in turn should be `async Task`, without `Task.Run` at all. `ReadLineAsync` is already asynchronous, `Task.Run` there just wastes a task and doesn't even use a thread, except to create the buffer and call `NewLine`

Comment: OK, thanks, I get it!